# On the content of LaTeX-environment in AucTeX

Tags: emacs, auctex

When inserting environments using `LaTeX-environment` in AucTeX, the candidate environment list varies from time to time. For example, I often insert the `equation*` environment. Sometimes this environment lies in the candidate list of this command, sometimes not.

I have no ideas why this happens. It seems the candidate list of `LaTeX-environment` is determined by a variable `LaTeX-environment-list`, which is buffer-local and auto-generated.

Can someone give me some hint how to set the candidate list of `LaTeX-environment`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`equation*` is not a predefined environment, it is defined by `amsmath` so auctex only offers it if it "knows" `amsmath` is in use, eg if you added the package using the "latex package" interaction, it is possible to arrange that latex loads `amsmath` wihout auctex updating the list of environments if you add this package by hand.

You can force the document to be reparsed with `C-u` `C-c` `C-n` The style hooks are then reloaded, so that, if you added the package by hand, its commands will be included in the list.

Comment: `C-u C-c C-n` is a good hint in that regard as well: it gets your document reparsed and the style hooks reloaded, so that, if you added the package by hand, it's commands will be included on the list.

Comment: @gusbrs ah thanks, I knew that was there somewhere, I'll add...

Comment: It's muscle memory to me by now. ;-) I'm only not sure if `C-u` is really needed for this case (I just tend to do it...).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and @gusbrs thanks! Your advice is really helpful and solves my problems like magic! But I still curious about how to added the package using the "latex package" interaction as mentioned by @DavidCarlisle. By using `M-x`, I don't find any command about adding a latex package. Even more unfortunately, if I google this question, the only answer I can find is about adding auctex package to emacs rather than adding a latex package.

Comment: @xiangsheng if for example you start an empty .tex file then add C-c C-e document  it promps for the document class and packages. packages added then are known but if you skip that and add `\usepackage` by hand, they are not until you re-parse.

Comment: @xiangsheng Or, if the document is already in place, adding a package with `C-c RET usepackage RET` will offer completion on the packages and already run the style file of the one you choose, thus adding its commands and environments to the list.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and @gusbrs thanks! By looking at the manual, I find that if I set `TeX-parse-self` to `t`, (which I've done before), the re-parse and adding environment procedure should happen automatically in theory. But I don't know when this option will come into work, so maybe that is why I sometimes find more environment is added, sometimes not.

Comment: @xiangsheng It probably already does, it does so when you open the file. But it cannot guess what you did if you just typed `\usepackage{package}`.

Comment: @gusbrs, I guess so, thank you!